# jQuery </body> tag possible?

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create an element after the closing body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792142/how-do-i-create-an-element-after-the-closing-body-tag)

Did a search, could not find this.

Is it possible to jQuery the closing `</body>` tag and then add some JS code just above?
IE: find:

```
$("</body>")
```

Then add some JS script just above this tag?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "closing tag" in the DOM. Tags, closing or otherwise, are a component of your markup, the DOM has only elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to select the 'closing' tag, just select the body and append what you want:

```
$('body').append('<h1>foobar</h1>');
```

**update**

As @meagar mentioned correctly, with jQuery you don't select a 'closing' tag, but the whole 'element', e.g. the body, or a 'paragraph' (p) as a whole

Trying to make it more clear, this code:

```
<body>
    <p>my paragraph</p>
    <script>
       $(body).append('<p>new paragraph</p>');
    </script>
</body>
```

Will produce this result:

```
<body>
    <p>my paragraph</p>
    <script>
       $(body).append('<p>new paragraph</p>');
    </script>
    <p>new paragraph</p>
</body>
```

The new paragraph is appended at the end of the body

Comment: Yes, but how can I have my code be the last big just before the body tag ends?

Comment: By using .append, as suggested. .append adds the content as the last thing in the target element.

Comment: Perfectly said Kevin. Thanks for the phrase "the last thing in..." All: thanks, that makes good sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.append()`.

```
$('body').append();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do that you would query for `body` and then use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```
$("body").append();
```

Answer (score 1):

To append content to the body use the following.

```
$('body').append(htmltoappend);
```

> Is it possible to jQuery the closing  tag and then add some JS
>   code just above?

Why would you want to insert *JS Code* above the closing body tag?

Comment: OP misunderstood the jQuery selector, and thought you had to select the *closing* tag to add some content at the end of the body

Comment: @thaJeztah - understood.  But still, JS code is much different then html so I'm unsure if the OP is just trying to add js to page

Comment: I've updated my answer, to clarify the result, hope this will help the OP to understand the workings of jQuery