# Does jQuery can use an end tag as a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am pretty new in jQuery. I cam across this jQuery code that uses `<div />` as a selector:

```
$("<div />").html(someString).text();
```

First of all, I would like to know if it is a legitimate tag to use, since `div` has an end tag: `</div>`.

But my main question - does jQuery can use an end tag as a selector and what would be the result of such code?

What will do such code? I did some research, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653978/jquery-body-tag-possible]), [meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) say:

> There is no such thing as a "closing tag" in the DOM. Tags, closing or otherwise, are a component of your markup, the DOM has only elements.

but does jQuery treat an end tag as reference to a DOM element like it treats an opening tag?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The whole code is in HTML, so I am not quite sure it will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See these:

1. `$("div")` its a selector which selects all the divs in the page.
2. `$("<div>")` This creates a dom node `<div></div>` because of `<tags>`.
3. `$("<div />")` and `$("<div></div>")` is also same as **2.**

So, in javascript there is a method called `document.createElement(tagName)`, which is used to create new elements in the page.

So basically jQuery has a different syntax but `document.createElement(tagName)` is used behind the scenes.

---

For you comment:

```js
var div = $('<div/>').html('<p>Hi!!!</p>').text(); // put a html string and get the text content of it.

document.body.textContent = div; // put the text content in the doc body.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. So what `$("<div />").html(someString).text();` will acually do?

Comment: This will create new element and read all the text nodes of it.

Comment: @Sipo check the demo added in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. In chrome, when this code runs, will I see a div created in the `elements` tab of the developers tools?

Comment: @Sipo no! because you are creating a div but you are not appending it to the DOM.

Comment: Why isn't it apeended to the DOM? Sorry if my questions are dumb lol. :)

Comment: @Sipo because in that snippet of code we don't have any code which is one of it like `.append(), .html(), .prepend(), .appendChild()` bound to doc body.

Answer (score 6):

It is not  a selector, we are creating a new dom element `div` and is setting its text content here.

If the parameter to [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) is a string and its first character is a `<` it the passed string is not considered as a selector, instead it is considered as a request to create a new element.

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with ).
>   If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as
>   explained above. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet,
>   jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.
>   Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these
>   elements. You can perform any of the usual jQuery methods on this
>   object:

Also it is not an end tag, it is a notation where the opening and closing notation are combined to one so it is the same as `<div></div>`

Comment: So, `<div />` is just a shortcut? And can you link to an article who expends on that topic? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sipo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Answer (score 2):

> I cam across this jQuery code that uses `<div />` as a selector

That isn't a selector. jQuery can accept a lot of different things as the first argument to the `jQuery`/`$` function. In this case it is a string of HTML, which will be used to create a *new element*.

---

> First of all, I would like to know if it is a legitimate tag to use

It isn't in HTML, but jQuery supports some custom syntax for element creation.

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> > When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$( "<img />" )` or `$( "<img>" )`, `$( "<a></a>" )` or `$( "<a>" )` — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript .createElement() function.

---

> does jQuery can use an end tag as a selector

No. When selecting elements from the DOM, jQuery can still only access *elements* — not start tags, not end tags, just complete elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a selector. Is a creation of the `<div>` tag. In normal cases, it appends after or before another element.

Note that this: `<div/>` is not a closing tag, is an open and close tag.

This:

```
 <div/>
```

is the same that this:

```
  <div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery if you want to create a new div element you can use `$("<div/>)` like this, Since we are passing a valid HTML content inside `$()` it will try to create that HTML.

Now this particular piece of code is used when we want to ***decode the HTML entities in a string***, check this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery) for details

```
var decodedString = $("<div />").html(someStringForDecoding).text();
```

This will return the decoded HTML entities in the string.

These are also valid codes to create `Div`

```
$("<div></div>").appendTo("div#anotherDiv");
$("<div>").attr('id','divId').appendTo('body');
```

Comment: So, <div /> is just a shortcut? And can you link to an article who expends on that topic? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, Check my edit to know the actual usage of your code.